# How can i validate a minimum amount of chars in my text box?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to validate a credit card security number, i've set the max length to 3 but i need to make sure that the users enters at least 3 and i cant find any minlength ways to do it.

Security: `<input type="text" name="secno" maxlength="3">`

```
var n=document.forms["myForm"]["secno"].value;
if (n==null || n=="" || isNaN(n)) {
  alert("Security number needed");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with javascript but general coding is there not a way to do a if n.length < 3 then tell them "security number invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
<input type="text" name="secno" onblur="if(this.value.length < 3 )alert('At least three chars.');" maxlength="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Security: <input type="text" name="secno" pattern=".{3,3}" />
```

Would work the same as minlength=3 and maxlength=3, but keep in mind some cards have four characters, so I'd suggest

```
Security: <input type="text" name="secno" pattern=".{3,4}" />
```

What this is doing, is using the pattern attribute, which lets you s et a regular expression to validate the test

Comment: It's just HTML5. Regular Expressions can be learned http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and it's used in pretty much every language you'll encounter. It's used for string matching and replacing

.{3,4}, means any 3 - 4 of any character. [0-9]{3,4} would only accept 3 - 4 numbers, where as [a-z]{3,15} would only accept 3 to 15 lower case letters

Comment: ah ok, had never used HTML5 validation.